# What is the preferred way to interact with WMI using LINQ

Tags: linq, wmi

I've seem some projects out there and was wondering if anyone had any feedback.
The level of maturity of these projects seems low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq to WMI looks pretty good.  I just downloaded it and had a look at it.

It basically wraps the ManagementObjectSearcher class of the System.Management namespace, builds an expression tree using the visitor pattern, executes your query and returns an IQueryable.

Simple and elegant, the code is a joy to look at.

http://linq2wmi.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=15434

Comment: I agree with this answer, but wanted to point out a limitation I ran into. I was able to do a join between Win32_Process and Win32_Thread, as an example, which worked fine until I tried to use the orderby clause which wasn't supported for joins. orderby for a single source works OK.  Additionally,  this project continues to be under development.